# Perl SOAP::Lite server

Tags: perl, soaplite

I've created the following SOAP::Lite server in Perl:

```
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
-> dispatch_to('Test')
-> handle;

package Test;
sub Calculate {

...

}
```

I then created a perl client to test the webservice and all went well.
But I had to create a WSDL file with information about this SOAP web service. When I tested the WSDL file in a generic online SOAP client (http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html) I started to get some errors, regarding the execution of the method Calculate, so I forced the use of this method using:

```
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
    -> dispatch_to('Test')
    -> on_action(sub { ($first, $second, $third) = @_; print $third; }
    -> handle;
```

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
Denied access to method (Calculate) in class (main)
```

Any help would be appreciated.